# email confirmation on signup in php while using local host as aserver

Tags: php, mysql, email

i am new to php and web development. i am trying to confirm user,s email on signup by sending confirmation message on their email. But it is not working is the problem with my using localhost as a server or there is some other problem? here is my code

```
 {
   $to = $_POST['email'];
 $com_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));
   $subject = "Confirmation from OnlineShopping to $_POST['username']";
   $header = "OnlineShopping: Confirmation from OnlineShopping";
   $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn";
   $message .= "http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";

   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

   if($sentmail)
            {
   echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
   }
   else
         {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
   }
  }
```

my if($sentmail) condition is coming true and i am getting message that your confirmation link has been sent to your email address but i am not receiving any email in my inbox

Comment: If your SMTP settings are not set, you can use [this tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) on your localhost to catch any outgoing mail sent from your PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, ISPs usually block any smtp activity, you need a proper mail server. Easiest is to use the gmail smtp server to send mail, just to get you going.

There are plenty of ways to do that, just search "gmail smtp php" and you'll get a bunch of articles.

Comment: i have heard that u have to edit php.ini file to do this. is there any such option?

Comment: here is a list of `php.ini` configurations http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

You need a host to send email with php. I recomend you to use [.tk](http://dot.tk) For a free domain and [hostinger](http://hostinger.com) for free hosting. So you can use this function and test your stuff.

But you can also try changing the php.ini file. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php